# How to draw colored text, multiline, monospaced

Tags: color, typography

Wondering how to draw this using different colors (such as each letter a different color) so that it appears in the document like this:

```
   / \  / ___| / ___|_ _|_ _|
  / _ \ \___ \| |    | | | | 
 / ___ \ ___) | |___ | | | | 
/_/   \_\____/ \____|___|___|
```

But A is blue, S is red, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\catcode`!=13
\def!#1!{\color{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
!red!   / \   !blue!/ ___| !green! / ___|!yellow!|_ _|!cyan!|_ _|
!red!  / _ \  !blue!\___ \ !green!| |    !yellow! | | !cyan! | | 
!red! / ___ \ !blue! ___) |!green!| |___ !yellow! | | !cyan! | | 
!red!/_/   \_\!blue!\____/ !green! \____|!yellow!|___|!cyan!|___|
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: How does `!red!` use all that follows as an argument (even if there are spaces between the characters that follow)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I used `\color` not `\textcolor`, that does not take an argument.

Comment: Thanks - I should have see this myself :).